# .Net Native UWP Symbols don't match crash dump

Tags: uwp

I am trying to obtain stack trace information from minidumps that were created from my UWP application that is using .Net Native compilation.  I have the pdbs that were in the ilc folder from my build server, but when I add those pdb to the symbol path, I get an error stating that the symbol file does not match.

Has anyone else run into this and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  After investigating further I found the path on the build machine that the crash dump said the symbols should be at.  After using that, I was able to debug.